# How do include a url from my urlconf in a template

Tags: django, url

the urls.py is:

```
url(r'^paypal',
        ListView.as_view(
            model=PaypalMail,
            context_object_name='paypal_email_links',
            template_name='tools/payment.html')),
```

I want to make a url in template

```
{% url xxxx %}
```

how to write it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly add a name to your url -

```
url(r'^paypal', ListView.as_view(model=PaypalMail,
       context_object_name='paypal_email_links',
       template_name='tools/payment.html'),
   name = 'paypal_view'),
```

Then construct your reverse function -

```
{% url 'paypal_view' %}
```

Have read of the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/http/urls/#naming-url-patterns) on naming url patterns.